# How to echo highest value of a centimeter for the whole day from sql using php

Tags: php, mysql, database, datetime

How to `echo` highest value of a centimeter for the whole day from **SQL** using **PHP**

this is my database :

```
-------------------------------
id | date       | centimeter  
------------------------------
1  | 2014-01-31 | 160    
2  | 2014-02-28 | 800   
3  | 2017-03-31 | 23   
4  | 2016-04-30 | 130 
5  | 2016-04-30 | 600 
6  | 2017-03-31 | 700  
7  | 2014-03-28 | 200
```

i want to echo it in **PHP** this way :

```
2017-03-31  700 
2016-04-30  600 
2014-03-28  200
```

*i want to echo only 1 highest centimeter by day

Answer (score 3):

```
select date, max(centimeter)
from your_table
group by date
```

Answer (score 0):

using `PDO`

```
$SQL = "SELECT date , MAX(centimeter) FROM TABLE_NAME GROUP BY date";

$connection = new PDO('mysql:host=HOST;dbname=DB_NAME;charset=utf8', 'USER_NAME', 'PASSWORD');
$stmt = $connection->prepare($SQL)
if($stmt)
{
  $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  var_dump($result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this may be it will help you

SELECT date, MAX(centimeter) from table_name GROUP BY by date ORDER BY date DESC;

Answer (score 0):

select max(mytbl.centimeter) as centimeterMax, SUBSTR(mytbl.date, 9,2) as DayOnly from ( SELECT * FROM mytbl) as mytbl group by DayOnly